# i cant refund my BNB from my contract on remix

Tags: web3js, solidity-0.5.x

my bnb stuck and I cant back it to my wallet!

here is the code I used

https://ghostbin.com/KgvTS/raw

my address
https://bscscan.com/address/0xf3321b8f53ed3051fd4f0ae139f04fd6a280c4b7#internaltx

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**You have been scammed.**

This contract just sends your BNB to a wallet that is presumably owned by the scammer.

Is it possible that you saw a video on youtube explaining how to make a lot of money doing arbitrage with this contract? This is a common scam.

Comment: yes , https://bscscan.com/address/0xf3321B8f53ED3051FD4F0Ae139f04fd6a280C4b7 its still here my bnb , any method to return it ?

Comment: Unless this is your address (you have the private key), no there is no way. This is most likely the scammers address. His address, his BNB.